# Why does the value of a mapping(bytes32 => uint8) seem to change between transaction calls?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

The contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.10;

contract Test {
    mapping (bytes32 => uint8) private dict;

    function Test() {}

    function Set(bytes32 key, uint8 val) returns (uint8) {
        dict[key] = val;
        return dict[key];
    }

    function Get(bytes32 key) returns (uint8) {
        return dict[key];
    }

}
```

and I run on testrpc:

```
contract_file = 'test/test.sol'
contract_name = ':Test'

Solc = require('solc')
Web3 = require('web3')

web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
source_code = fs.readFileSync(contract_file).toString()

compiledContract = Solc.compile(source_code)
abi = compiledContract.contracts[contract_name].interface
bytecode = compiledContract.contracts[contract_name].bytecode;
ContractClass =  web3.eth.contract(JSON.parse(abi))

contract_init_data = {
    data: bytecode,
    from: web3.eth.accounts[0],
    gas: 1000000,
}

deployed_contract = ContractClass.new(contract_init_data)

deployed_contract.Set.call("akey", 5)
deployed_contract.Get.call("akey")
```

bizarrely, this is the output I get in the node terminal:

```
> deployed_contract.Set.call("akey", 5)
{ [String: '5'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 5 ] }
> deployed_contract.Get.call("akey")
{ [String: '0'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] }
```

This result is the outcome of a long debugging session... what is going on? It seems distinctly like something is broken here, but I followed [a tutorial](https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-1-40d2d0d807c2) which did something very similar which seems to work...

also:

```
> Solc.version()
'0.4.11+commit.68ef5810.Emscripten.clang'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `deployed_contract.Set("akey", 5)` without .call

Because .call on your setter method

> executes a message call transaction, which is directly executed in the
>   VM of the node, but never mined into the blockchain.

[doc](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcall)

The value of the map does not change. I bet 0 is the default value when nothing is set

By the way try using the [online compiler](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-v0.4.11+commit.68ef5810.js) you will quickly see if the problem is on the contract or the way you interact with it with web3.